# C++ code runs sometimes but other times it either hangs or throws exceptions

Tags: c++

I wrote a C++ program that merges sorted sub-arrays, but my issue is that when I run the code using Visual Studio it runs perfectly fine sometimes, but other times it doesn't (I'd say it runs without issues ~40% of the time), when it doesn't run as intended it either hangs at a certain point or it throws exceptions, sometimes the exception is heap corruption, other times it just says that (myapp).exe has triggered a breakpoint. Also, another issue I'm having is when I try to delete my dynamic array I get an error, the error I get is at the end of the post and the dynamic array that I'm trying to delete is commented out at the end of the MergeSubArrays code snippet.

```
void MergeSubArrays(int arr[], int size, int R) {
    int lP, rP, lLimit, rLimit, p = 0, c = 0, rC = R;
    int* temp = new int[size];
    bool breakOut = false;
    while (R < size) {
        lP = 0, rP = R, lLimit = R, rLimit = R * 2;
        while (p < size) {
            while (lP < lLimit && rP < rLimit) {
                if (arr[lP] < arr[rP]) {
                    temp[p] = arr[lP];
                    p++;
                    lP++;
                }
                else {
                    temp[p] = arr[rP];
                    p++;
                    rP++;
                }
            }
            while (lP < lLimit) {
                temp[p] = arr[lP];
                p++;
                lP++;
            }
            while (rP < rLimit) {
                temp[p] = arr[rP];
                p++;
                rP++;
            }
            for (;c < p;c++) {
                arr[c] = temp[c];
            }
            if ((rLimit + 2 * R) <= size) {
                rLimit += (2 * R);
                lLimit += (2 * R);
                lP += R; rP += R;
            }
            else {
                break;
                breakOut = true;
            }
            if (breakOut) break;
        }
        if (breakOut) break;
        p = 0; c = 0; R += R;
    }
    if (rLimit < size) {
        p = 0; c = 0; lP = 0;
        while (lP < rLimit && rP < size) {
            if (arr[lP] < arr[rP]) {
                temp[p] = arr[lP];
                p++;
                lP++;
            }
            else {
                temp[p] = arr[rP];
                p++;
                rP++;
            }
            while (lP < rLimit) {
                temp[p] = arr[lP];
                p++;
                lP++;
            }
            while (rP < size) {
                temp[p] = arr[rP];
                p++;
                rP++;
            }
            for (;c < size;c++) {
                arr[c] = temp[c];
            }
        }
    }
  /*delete[] temp; <-- this results in a breakpoint with a code snippet that I'll show at the end of
                       the post*/
}
```

```
void SortIntoSubArrays(int arr[], int begin, int end) {
    if (begin < end) {
        int j, key, pos;
        for (int i = begin;i < end;i++) {
            j = i - 1;
            key = arr[i];
            pos = BinarySearch(arr, key, begin, j);

            while (j >= pos) {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                j--;
            }
            arr[j + 1] = key;
        }
    }
}
```

```
int main() {
    int size = 15;
    int* arr = new int[size];
    arr[0] = 5; arr[1] = 2; arr[2] = 10; arr[3] = 1; arr[4] = 8; arr[5] = 3; arr[6] = 12; arr[7] = 4; 
    arr[8] = 7; arr[9] = 20; arr[10] = 15; arr[11] = 17;  arr[12] = 5; arr[13] = 40; arr[14] = 45;
    int R = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < size;i += R) {
        if (i + R <= size) InsertionSort2(arr, i, i + R);
        else SortIntoSubArrays(arr, i, size);
    }
    MergeSubArrays(arr, 15, R);
    for (int i = 0;i < size;i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I try to add `delete[] temp;` in the MergeSubArrays function:

```
CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

edit: Fixed the issue, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're writing past the end of `temp`. Change `temp` to be a `std::vector`, and use `at()` instead of `[]` to find where.

Comment: time to use vectors... this looks more to C than C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often when it may run sometimes and not other can be attributed to a memory leak. Sometimes you may get lucky and the leak wont corrupt other data but often it does curropt other data.

Try using a prebuilt list class from the std library with error catching and see what error it throughs and then fix it. One last thing if that does not work check compiler options as that may disable the error checking

Edit: most licky cause is an invalid write not a leak. Thanks guy in comments.

Comment: A leak is very unlikely to corrupt data.  Did you mean performing invalid writes?